# CNN Pytorch Error Input type (torch.cuda.ByteTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

This is the code for learning about 5000 images by dividing them into 8 classes with PyTorch.
The code reads a csv file consisting of image file names labeled 0-7.
It comes out well in imshow and is categorized well.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 16
EPOCHS = 10

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, img_dir, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.img_labels = pd.read_csv(csv_file)        
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1])
        image = read_image(img_path)
        label = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.target_transform:
            label = self.target_transform(label)
        return image, label

train_data = CustomImageDataset("../train.csv",
                                   ".././Taekwondo/DataSet/train_Image",
                                   None, None)
test_data = CustomImageDataset("../test.csv",
                               ".././Taekwondo/DataSet/test_Image",
                               None, None)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = train_data,
                                           batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                           shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_data,
                                        batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                        shuffle=True)

class Net(nn.Module):                
    def __init__(self):   
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32,64, 3)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2,
                                 stride = 2)
        self.fc1=nn.Linear(16*16*32,128)
        self.fc2=nn.Linear(128,8)
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 16*16*32)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.log_softmax(x,dim=1)
        return x

net = Net()

model=Net().to(DEVICE)                 
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.001)
criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
print(model)

def train(model, train_loader, optimizer, log_interval):
    model.train()         
    for batch_idx,(image, label) in enumerate(train_loader):
        image=image.to(DEVICE)
        label=label.to(DEVICE)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output=model(image)
        loss=criterion(output,label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        if batch_idx % log_interval==0:
            print("Train Epoch: {}[{}/{}({:.0f}%)]\tTrain Loss: {:.6f}"
                  .format(Epoch,batch_idx * len(image),
                len(train_loader.dataset),100.*batch_idx/len(train_loader),loss.item()))

def evaluate(model,test_loader):
    model.eval()                  
    test_loss=0
    correct=0
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        for image, label in test_loader:
            image=image.to(DEVICE)              
            label=label.to(DEVICE)              
            output=model(image)                 
            test_loss+=criterion(output,label).item()
            prediction = output.max(1,keepdim = True)[1]
            correct += prediction.eq(label.view_as(prediction)).sum().item()
    
    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
    test_accuracy=100.*correct / len(test_loader.dataset)
    return test_loss, test_accuracy
```

However, when I try to learn it, the following error keeps appearing in the last block.

```
for Epoch in range(1,EPOCHS + 1):
    train(model,train_loader,optimizer,log_interval = 200)
    test_loss, test_accuracy=evaluate(model, test_loader)
    print("\n[EPOCH: {}], \tTest Loss: {:.4f}, \tTest Accuracy: {:.2f} %\n".
        format(Epoch,test_loss,test_accuracy))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\JupyterTest\CNN\CNN-Copy3.ipynb Cell 15' in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for Epoch in range(1,EPOCHS + 1):
----> 2     train(model,train_loader,optimizer,log_interval = 200)
      3     test_loss, test_accuracy=evaluate(model, test_loader)
      4     print("\n[EPOCH: {}], \tTest Loss: {:.4f}, \tTest Accuracy: {:.2f} %\n".
      5         format(Epoch,test_loss,test_accuracy))

c:\JupyterTest\CNN\CNN-Copy3.ipynb Cell 13' in train(model, train_loader, optimizer, log_interval)
      5 label=label.to(DEVICE)
      6 optimizer.zero_grad()
----> 7 output=model(image)
      8 loss=criterion(output,label)
      9 loss.backward()

File c:\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1110, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1106 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1107 # this function, and just call forward.
   1108 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

c:\JupyterTest\CNN\CNN-Copy3.ipynb Cell 7' in Net.forward(self, x)
     28     def forward(self,x):
---> 29         x = self.conv1(x)
     30 #        print(x.shape)  
     31 #        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
     32         x = F.relu(x)

File c:\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1110, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1106 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1107 # this function, and just call forward.
   1108 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File c:\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py:447, in Conv2d.forward(self, input)
    446 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 447     return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)

File c:\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py:443, in Conv2d._conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    439 if self.padding_mode != 'zeros':
    440     return F.conv2d(F.pad(input, self._reversed_padding_repeated_twice, mode=self.padding_mode),
    441                     weight, bias, self.stride,
    442                     _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 443 return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    444                 self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)

RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.ByteTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

I think it's a batch size problem in the CNN structure, but an error occurs no matter what number you put in. Please help...

Comment: This error is not related to the mini-batch size. Please check the input data type, `image.dtype`, confirm it matches the dtype of the weight (i.e. float). Visualizing the input data would help to check if it is well constructed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the data type problem is solved!

X_train: torch.Size([16, 3, 424, 776]) type: torch.ByteTensor
Y_train: torch.Size([16]) type: torch.LongTensor

By attaching .float() to all variables of def train and def evaluate, the data type problem was solved. But now I got the following error as ValueError.

>> Expected input batch_size (2208) to match target batch_size (16).

I've seen other questions related to this error and tested by changing the parameters of conv1~4, but I don't know what is the correct number. Can you help me with this too?